# Array Formula only works in first cell

Tags: arrays, excel

I have adapted the following array i found online.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))
```

below is my version.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Master!$B$4:$B$647, SMALL(IF($O$11=Master!A4:A828, ROW(Master!$A$4:$A$828)-ROW(Master!$A$4)+1),ROW(Master!1:1))),"")}
```

This works fine in the first cell but when i drag it down it displays randomly. This is the first time i have dealt with array formulas and to be honest i do not fully understand them yet.

I am hoping someone could help me figure out why it stops working in the other cells?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have the relative/Absolute references backwards on `$O$11=Master!A4:A828`  should be `$O$11=Master!$A$4:$A$828`

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked.